# Google Now style three-dot menu in Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, google-now

I mimic the Google Now card style, and now I want to have the three-dot menu on each card to display further advanced options that are possible with this list item.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how they made it. It seems similar to the onOptionsItemSelected.

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you use this CardLib project: https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib

It's pretty comprehensive in providing card themed UI with nearly all the features one would need.

Comment: I was looking for it, and just found it.

Comment: I clicked this question to suggest the very same library.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look in how they do it in their library.

Answer (score 1):

A simple imageView will do. Put an imageview (of the 3 dot menu icon) in your listview list layout and then simply call it's `onClickListener` in bindView or any other relevant method.

For example, you can use a SimpleCursorAdapter and override it's `bindView()` method.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
ImageView overflowMenu = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourId);
overflowMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
      //Get position of the item clicked
      final int position = getListView().getPositionForView((LinearLayout)v.getParent());
      //Get the cursor of the item clicked
      final Cursor c = (Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
      }
}
```